# pyinstaller - mkdir error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to create executable with pyinstaller (in ubuntu). My program works, but when I create executable, program doesn't work. Problem is probably in command os.mkdir. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: where is the sample code? Error message? permissions of parent directory? You give us nothing to help you fix your problem.

Comment: I had the same problem and found this recent bug report about it https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1765 but unfortunately no clear work around.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is indeed `os.makedir` you will need to run the program as administrator, or pick a non-protected folder to `mkdir` in ...

Unfortunately is sounds like you are not sure this is the problem, if you build your executable with `--console` flag you will probably get output that tells you exactly what the problem is...

Comment: If I run program as administrator, it also doesn't work. If I run program in IDLE editor, it works well, but problem is when I run executable file (generated with pyinstaller).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If you want to create a directory where you want to store some files, you can create it by using `os.system("mkdir $nameOfDirectory$")`. Hope this helps, `os.system()` executes in Terminal the command between the paranthesis.

Comment: .... this wont help him ... os.makedir is the correct way to make a directory in python ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley It worked for me. I have also created application installers using Python. And anyway, if he doesn't find the problem, this could be a good alternative.

Comment: the shell that is spawned has the same permissions as the python app (or exe in this case.) Im 90% sure that he is trying to write to a location where he is not permitted to without running as admin ... but who knows maybe your right ...